# Extract loaded jar into oracle database

Tags: oracle, jar, oracle11g, loadjava

There is a jar that was loaded into an oracle database using loadjava command. Is there a way to extract this jar(or the classes) loaded into the database. The database version is 11g.

Answer (score 0):

For java class.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('JAVA_SOURCE','class_name') from dual;
```

Comment: The problem is that the class is loaded from a jar, and it's already compiled. The class I am looking for does not have the source loaded in the database.